# Storing only date part in Cassandra using timestamp type

Tags: cassandra

have below mentioned column family in cassandra.

```
create table user_interactions ( user_id bigint, logged_in timestamp , module list<text>, primary key (user_id,logged_in));
```

now when i insert the record it stores always time information too. Can i have only date to be part of logged_in value. I do not need time because objective is to have all user interactions getting stored on daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of timestamp you can use string and pass in your value of date to that string.

Comment: If you go down the string route, do yourself a favor and use the ISO text representation of the date. Why not store the long of the date (at midnight)?